# Possible to scope a javascript variable to a function and that function's recursive calls to itself?

Tags: javascript

I am in a situation where I have a loop that is calling a function.  The function will make recursive calls to itself once called.

Is there a way that I can scope a variable to the function and the chain of recursive calls generated from the first call?

Something like this:

```
for(var i=0;i<100;i++)
{
  myFunction();
}

function myFunction()
{
   var someNumber = 200;
   someNumber -= 10;
   if( someNumber > 0)
   {
      myFunction();
   }
}
```

where at the second iteration of the first call to someNumber would be 190 and not 200.  Is this possible to accomplish?

If there is anything confusing here, please let me know.

Comment: That's not how a `while` loop works. And is there some reason you don't just declare the variable outside of `myFunction`, and the reinitialize inside the loop? As long as your code is synchronous, it will work fine. [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cjV4V/)

Comment: I mistyped, it's supposed to be a `for`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use an inner function to do the recursion:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    myFunction();
}

function myFunction()
{
    var someNumber = 200;
    (function innerFunction()
    {
        someNumber -= 10;
        if( someNumber > 0)
        {
            innerFunction();
        }
    })();
};
```

Note, you have a syntax error.  Your `while` needs to be `for`.

**Edit:** Perhaps your real code is different and calls for a recursive function, but your example would be much simpler by just using a loop:

```
function myFunction()
{
    for (var someNumber = 200; someNumber > 0; someNumber -= 10)
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: Note, the syntax for **ReactJS** users is `var funcName = function() {...}.bind(this);`

Answer (score 2):

```
while(var i=0;i<100;i++)
{
  myFunction(200);
}

function myFunction(someNumber)
{
   someNumber -= 10;
   if( someNumber > 0)
   {
      myFunction(someNumber);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no--you should be able to accomplish the task by passing the value of the variable in as a parameter of `myFunction`.  The first call will need to set the starting value, then pass it along for future invocations to modify.

```
while(var i=0;i<100;i++)
{
  myFunction();
}


function myFunction(seed) {
    if (seed == undefined)
    {
        seed = 200;
    }

    alert(seed);

    var newSeed = seed - 50;
    if (seed > 0)
    {
        myFunction(newSeed);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using objects would be the way to go if you want to do something where you are actually scoping variables.

```
function myObject(_someNumber) {
    var someNumber = _someNumber;

    this.myFunction = function() {
        this.someNumber -= 10;
        if(this.someNumber > 0)
        {
           this.myFunction(this.someNumber);
        }
    }
}

for(var i=0;i<100;i++)
{
  new myObject().myFunction(someNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a closure.  Well, you might not want it, but it will do what you are asking.

```
(function() {
    var someNumber=200;
    myFunction=function() {
        someNumber-=10;
        if (someNumber > 0) {
            myFunction();
        }
    }
})();
```

But properly passing parameters is probably a better idea.